# Singleton как правильно интегрировать

Tags: java

у меня есть код `Stopwatch`. С помощью `Singleton` я хочу сделать, так, что бы при повторном запуске `Stopwatch` открывался уже работающий. Возможно это реализовать? Или я сильно ошибаюсь в возможностях `Singletone`?

Код `Stopwatch`:

```html
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Stopwatch implements ActionListener{


        JButton button = new JButton("knopka");
        JFrame frame_timer = new JFrame();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JButton startButton = new JButton("start");
        JButton resetButton = new JButton("reset");
        JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel();
        int elapsedTime = 0;
        int seconds =0;
        int minutes =0;
        int hours=0;
        boolean started = false;
        String seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
        String minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
        String hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours); 
    
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                elapsedTime=elapsedTime+1000;
                hours = (elapsedTime/3600000);
                minutes = (elapsedTime/60000)%60;
                seconds = (elapsedTime/1000)%60;
                seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
                minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
                hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours);
                
                timeLabel.setText(hours_string+":"+minutes_string+":"+seconds_string);
            }
            
            
        });
        
        public Stopwatch(){
            
            timeLabel.setText(hours_string+"-"+minutes_string+"-"+seconds_string);
            timeLabel.setBounds(100,100,200,100);
            timeLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana",Font.PLAIN,35));
            timeLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1));
            timeLabel.setOpaque(true);
            timeLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    
            startButton.setBounds(100,100,200,50);
            startButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,20));
            startButton.setFocusable(false);
            startButton.addActionListener(this);
            
            resetButton.setBounds(100,150,200,50);
            resetButton.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.PLAIN,20));
            resetButton.setFocusable(false);
            resetButton.addActionListener(this);
            
            frame.add(startButton);
            frame.add(resetButton);
            frame.add(timeLabel);
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(420,420);
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
            frame_timer.add(timeLabel);
            frame_timer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame_timer.setSize(420,420);
            frame_timer.setLayout(null);
            frame_timer.add(timeLabel);
            frame_timer.setVisible(true);
        }


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            if(e.getSource()==startButton) {
                start();
                if(started==false) {
                    started=true;
                    startButton.setText("stop");
                    start();
                }
                else {
                    started=false;
                    startButton.setText("continue");
        
                    stop();
                }
            }

                        if(e.getSource()==resetButton){
                started=false;
                startButton.setText("start");
                reset(); }
                }
    
        
void start() {
    timer.start();
    }
void stop() {
    timer.stop();
}
void reset() {
    timer.stop();
    elapsedTime=0;
    seconds=0;
    minutes=0;
    hours=0;
    seconds_string = String.format("%02d", seconds);
    minutes_string = String.format("%02d", minutes);
    hours_string = String.format("%02d", hours);
    timeLabel.setText(hours_string+":"+minutes_string+":"+seconds_string);
}


    

public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}


public static Object getDelay() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public String getDuration() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


public void showLogFile() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
}
}
```

Код `Singletone`:

```html
public class Singleton {
  private static Singleton Stopwatch;
  private Singleton () {};

  public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if (Stopwatch == null) {
      Stopwatch = new Singleton();
    }
    return Stopwatch;
  }
}
```

Даже если не верно написан код паттерна, куда его вставлять ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется вы не совсем понимаете, что такое `Singletone`. Синглтон - это паттерн проектирования, позволяющий создать единственный объект, владеющий ресурсом в программе, методом запрета копирования. Т.е вы не сможете создать копию объекта-владельца. При этом вам никто не запрещает (кроме логики) создать два синглтона с разными ресурсами, но одинаковым содержимым. А при особом извращенном желании - и два синглтона, владеющих одним ресурсом.
А при чем здесь запуск процесса? Для этого вы в коде должны проверять не запущен ли уже такой процесс, и если запущен - выходить, чтобы не было копии одного и того же процесса.